# sql to get lastest node of hierarchy base table?

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a table data like this

```
id = 1, parent = 0
id = 2, parent = 1
id = 3, parent = 1
id = 4, parent = 1

id = 5, parent = 0
id = 6, parent = 5
id = 7, parent = 5
id = 8, parent = 5

id = 9, parent = 0
```

now i want to get result like this, only latest node of the tree 
how can i do this ?

```
id = 4, parent = 1
id = 8, parent = 5
id =9, parent = 0
```

EDIT 1: What if I set the root node's parent_id = id? That would mean I could group by parent id. I'm just worried that this will cause problems in the future when I need to get the root node (meaning, no longer will I just query for WHERE parent_id = 0; i would have to do WHERE id = parent_id)

Comment: MySQL doesn't have hierarchical functions

Comment: yes but i should be able to get result that using normal sql, without using hierarchical functions right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that nodes with higher ids are "later", then it is just:

```
select max(id), parent from tree group by parent;
```

As for the root node, surely that would have to be inserted first, and so would have a known id such as 1 or 0, or could have a special parent id suchas NULL or -1.

Comment: Yeah thanx it gives me correct result 4,8,9. But if change data a bit say i only have data like id 1, 2, 3, 4 as in above example. It shows me 1 and 4 both. It should have shown me 4 only right? What I need to adjust to this sql?

Comment: 1 is the most recently added child of zero, and 4 si the most recent child of 1, so that is correct, isn't it ?

Comment: int the end what i did was made parent = id no more zero(0) for parent, example: if new row is id = 1 then parent = 1 as well and thus your sql gave what i was seeking.. thanx a lot